# My picking interface for my microbit isnt working

Tags: python, user-interface

Currently, I am making a game with microbit. I have three games for the players to pick but when I start my microbit, it automatically starts game three. This is a very troublesome problem. There is also another problem and that is my game 3 is not working. When I press pin 0 or pin 2, the game does snap the dot but then keeps repeating the game over score: 0 message and doesn't go back to the user interface. There are mainly two problems in my code. Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
def flipping():
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.SKULL)
    basic.pause(500)
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.SNAKE)
    basic.pause(500)
def game2():
    global always_true, game_name, game_stat, coin
    always_true = True
    game_name = "coin flip"
    game_stat = False
    basic.show_string("Game 2")
    basic.show_string("Coin Flip")
    basic.show_string("PIN 0 or PIN 2: Flip")
    basic.pause(100)
    game_stat = True
    while game_name == "coin flip" and game_stat == True:
        if pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P0) == 1 or pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P2) == 1:
            coin = randint(1, 2)
            for index in range(3):
                flipping()
            if coin == 1:
                basic.show_icon(IconNames.SKULL)
                basic.pause(500)
                basic.show_string("Heads!")
                game_stat = False
            elif coin == 2:
                basic.show_icon(IconNames.SNAKE)
                basic.pause(500)
                basic.show_string("Tails!")
                game_stat = False
        else:
            always_true = True
        if game_stat == False:
            game_name = "none"
            pickui()
def game3():
    global always_true, game_name, game_stat, dot
    always_true = True
    game_name = "snap the dot"
    game_stat = False
    basic.show_string("Game 3")
    basic.show_string("Snap the Dot")
    basic.show_string("PIN 0 or PIN 2: Snap")
    basic.pause(100)
    game_stat = True
    dot = game.create_sprite(2, 2)
    while game_name == "snap the dot" and game_stat == True:
        basic.pause(125)
        dot.move(1)
        dot.if_on_edge_bounce()
        if pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P0) == 1 or pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P2) == 1:
            if dot.get(LedSpriteProperty.X) == 2:
                game.add_score(1)
            else:
                game_stat = False
                game.game_over()
        else:
            always_true = True
        if game_stat == False:
            game_name = "none"
            pickui()
def game1():
    global always_true, game_name, rps_choice, bot_rps_choice, game_stat, bot_rps_choice_number
    always_true = True
    game_name = "rps"
    rps_choice = "none"
    bot_rps_choice = "none"
    game_stat = False
    basic.show_string("Game 1")
    basic.show_string("RPS")
    basic.show_string("Shake: Rock")
    basic.show_string("Tilt Left: Paper")
    basic.show_string("Tilt Right: Scissors")
    basic.pause(100)
    game_stat = True
    while game_name == "rps" and game_stat == True:
        if input.is_gesture(Gesture.SHAKE):
            rps_choice = "rock"
            bot_rps_choice_number = randint(1, 3)
            if bot_rps_choice_number == 1:
                bot_rps_choice = "rock"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 2:
                bot_rps_choice = "paper"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 3:
                bot_rps_choice = "scissors"
            if bot_rps_choice == "rock":
                basic.show_string("Tie!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "paper":
                basic.show_string("Lose!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "scissors":
                basic.show_string("Win!")
                game_stat = False
        elif pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P0) == 1:
            rps_choice = "paper"
            if bot_rps_choice_number == 1:
                bot_rps_choice = "rock"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 2:
                bot_rps_choice = "paper"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 3:
                bot_rps_choice = "paper"
            if bot_rps_choice == "rock":
                basic.show_string("Win!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "paper":
                basic.show_string("Tie!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "scissors":
                basic.show_string("Lose!")
                game_stat = False
        elif pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P2) == 1:
            rps_choice = "scissors"
            if bot_rps_choice_number == 1:
                bot_rps_choice = "rock"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 2:
                bot_rps_choice = "paper"
            elif bot_rps_choice_number == 3:
                bot_rps_choice = "paper"
            if bot_rps_choice == "rock":
                basic.show_string("Lose!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "paper":
                basic.show_string("Win!")
                game_stat = False
            elif bot_rps_choice == "scissors":
                basic.show_string("Tie!")
                game_stat = False
        else:
            always_true = True
        if game_stat == False:
            game_name = "none"
            pickui()
def pickui():
    global always_true, game_name, rps_choice, bot_rps_choice, game_stat, pick_time
    basic.show_string("Loading...")
    always_true = True
    game_name = "none"
    rps_choice = "none"
    bot_rps_choice = "none"
    game_stat = False
    basic.pause(5000)
    basic.clear_screen()
    if pick_time == "zero":
        basic.show_string("Shake: RPS")
        basic.show_string("PIN 0: Coin Flip")
        basic.show_string("PIN 2: Snap the Dot")
    elif pick_time == "one":
        basic.show_string("Please pick")
    game_name = "pick ui"
    while game_name == "pick ui":
        if input.is_gesture(Gesture.SHAKE):
            game1()
            pick_time = "one"
            game_name = "rps"
        elif pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P0) == 1:
            game2()
            pick_time = "one"
            game_name = "coin flip"
        elif pins.digital_read_pin(DigitalPin.P2) == 1:
            game3()
            pick_time = "one"
            game_name = "snap the dot"
bot_rps_choice_number = 0
dot: game.LedSprite = None
coin = 0
game_stat = False
bot_rps_choice = ""
rps_choice = ""
game_name = ""
always_true = False
pick_time = ""
pick_time = "zero"
always_true = True
game_name = "none"
rps_choice = "none"
bot_rps_choice = "none"
game_stat = False
pickui()
```

If anyone can tell me the problem, I would be very thankful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you'r setting the variables 3 or more times ,is quite obvious that you'll end up to not understand what are you doing

Comment: this code have multiple problems, like wtf is input.is_gesture(Gesture.SHAKE)? you're using some package that you're not telling to us, like what is basic?

Comment: Perhaps call game() after setting the game_name

Comment: i think you must understand more the concept of scope and call order, if you call a function inside another function, the main function get paused, the sub function get executed, and then we come back to the main function execution

Comment: while game_name == "pick ui": unclean goal of the loop, why do you need it?